# if cookies are disabled, unhide a div showing error

Tags: javascript, cookies

Excuse me for I am quite the novice when it comes to JavaScript. I want to have a div which currently has a `display:none` to unhide onload if the are_cookies_enabled() function returns false. However, my div is not unhiding so to say. If I encase it in a jquery onload, by itself, it works. What am I doing wrong?

*Note the function in noCookies is set to true (this is just to see if the unhide feature is working, since I have cookies enabled).*

```
    function are_cookies_enabled()
    {
        var cookieEnabled = (navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false;

        if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled == "undefined" && !cookieEnabled)
        { 
            document.cookie="testcookie";
            cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie") != -1) ? true : false;
        }
        return (cookieEnabled);
    }
    function noCookies()
    {
        if (are_cookies_enabled() == true) {
            document.getElementById('nocookie').style.display='block';
        }
    }
    window.onload = noCookies();
```

DIV:

```
<div id="nocookie" style="display:none;"><div class="ec-messages messages-warning">This site may not function properly if cookies are disabled. Session variables are stored in cookies. Please enable cookies.</div></div>
```

Comment: maybe this code runs before the DOM is built?

Comment: ah yes. that would make sense. should i execute it at the end? any suggestions? or just encase the nocookies() in a jquery onload

Comment: I am interested in making this work. I believe I have bad traffic visiting my site and I feel that this will help me block those bad visitors. Anyone else have some alternative script they think could work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `window.onload = noCookies()` to `window.onload = noCookies`.

`window.onload` is an event handler to handle the "load" event [[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onload)], so if you assign your `noCookies` function to `window.onload`, the function will be called when "load" event fires.

However, in your code, the **return value** of the function (which is undefined) is assigned to `window.onload`, no doubt it won't work.

Comment: @Alex I've updated my answer, hopefully it becomes more helpful to you.